# how to call npm in nw.exe (node-webkit) instead of nodejs.exe?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using node-webkit https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit on windows.
I want to use npm to update package "request" or any other package.
I have not installed nodejs on windows. I found npm.cmd needs nodejs.exe. Is there anyway that I can run/ call npm with node-webkit instead nodejs.exe? node-webkit gives nw.exe.

Thanks,
regards,
Maheshwar

Answer (score -1):

We called npm  as child process. We write update.bat as "npm update package"
Now, npm auto updates our package like windows update.